# JsonObjectRequest between Web Api and Android application

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, android-volley, controllers

I have tried mostly everything, I'm so frustrated at this stage, I would love if I can get an json object on the android side to use to populate a viewlist, I have tried formatting the json being sent in every way I possibly know how. Any suggestions would be amazing and very appreciated.

The JsonStringRequest recieves the json fine as a string, however to parse it to something useful has been a pain and I haven't managed to get a efficient way for the whole project. Trying to convert the string to either an JsonObject or Array fail with the same error.

The JsonArray- and Object-Request have both failed with similar error.

I have a feeling its not android side but the way I am sending the json from the rest service, or the way Volley is handling it.

**Asp.net Web Api Controller class**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[RoutePrefix("users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult getUsers()
    {
        User[] users = new User[] 
    { 
        new User { userID = "one", Name = "Tomato Soup", Surname = "Groceries", Nickname = "boogie" }, 
        new User { userID = "two", Name = "Tomato Soup", Surname = "Groceries", Nickname = "boogie" }
    };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
        return Json(json);
    }
}
```

**The JSON for what is being sent:**

"[{\"userID\":\"one\",\"Name\":\"Tomato Soup\",\"Surname\":\"Groceries\",\"Nickname\":\"boogie\"},{\"userID\":\"two\",\"Name\":\"Tomato Soup\",\"Surname\":\"Groceries\",\"Nickname\":\"boogie\"}]"

**The XML for what is being sent:**

[{"userID":"one","Name":"Tomato Soup","Surname":"Groceries","Nickname":"boogie"},{"userID":"two","Name":"Tomato Soup","Surname":"Groceries","Nickname":"boogie"}]

**Android side request:**

```
JsonObjectRequest (Very similar to JsonArrayRequest):

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest("http://10.0.0.3/users",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    Log.w("##########", response.toString());
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.w("##########", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    ) ;
    queue.add(request);
```

**StringRequest:**

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest("http://10.0.0.3/users", new Response.Listener<String>(){
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jar = new JSONObject(response);
            }
            catch(JSONException error)
            {
                Log.w("error", error.getMessage());
            }
            Log.w("############", response);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.w("error", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
    queue.add(req);
```

**Logcat error:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"userID":"one","Name":"Tomato Soup","Surname":"Groceries","Nickname":"boogie"},{"userID":"two","Name":"Tomato Soup","Surname":"Groceries","Nickname":"boogie"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the result is a `JSONArray`, you can use a `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`. If you have used `JsonArrayRequest` already and had any error, please post the error message or any logcat information with that `JsonArrayRequest`.

You can go [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) for more information

> JSONObject: ...A string beginning with **{** (left brace) and ending with **}** (right brace).
>
> JSONArray: ...A string that begins with **[** (left bracket) and ends with **]** (right bracket).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I figured it out. I was double serializing the user array object, it seems if I return the object without using the JsonConvert.SerializeObject it automatically serializes the object into a json. I'm not sure if its because its inherent to web api 2 (haven't read all the documentation yet). But thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, `return Json(json)` will jsonify your json!

Comment: to return json(json) is to only my browser to view the 'data' as json not xml. It's this line of code that was double converts it JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users).

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users)` produces `json`. `return Json(json)` then json's your json!